# Lauterbach Trace Function Micro Trace

Tags: trace, lauterbach

I would like to en-quire whether Lauterbach able to trace any data without elf file or symbol file loaded to the target board? My target board is LPC1768

We would like to know whether Trace function is working without any symbol file or .elf file loaded to the target board.

Answer (score 0):

For trace recording and decoding, the MicroTrace must be able to read the program code from your target's memory (which is normally possible) and must have access to your physical trace pins (TRACECLK, TRACEDATA[0..3]) usually via a MIPI20T debug connector.

If both is possible, you can trace your program code. **You do not need to have an ELF or any other file containing debug symbols.** However, finding any issue is of course a lot more easier, if your have debug symbols (e.g. from an ELF).

I hope your are not using the tiny [Arm Mbed LPC1768 Board](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-microcontrollers/general-purpose-mcus/lpc1700-arm-cortex-m3/arm-mbed-lpc1768-board:OM11043), because that board does give you direct access to the debug interface (JTAG, SWO) nor to the trace clock, which makes it not suitable for any external debug and trace tool (like MicroTrace).

Comment: Hello Mr. Holger, thank you for your quick response. I am using LPC1768 on MCB1700 board. I am currently using Microtrace LA4530 to test with script given on T32software demo script mcb1760 off chip trace demo. I have disable the line with data.load.elf, when i run the script, the data list shown question mark , and no trace list showing.  Do I need to set the physical trace pins on the board?

Comment: Nice evaluation board! I think you should check the processor's user manual and/or data sheet on how to set the pin multiplexer, so that the trace signals are actually connected to the physical pins. You set the correct multiplexing probably with the right Data.Set command. The script from Lauterbach should usually do that for you. If you are facing problems with that, I suggest to contact the Lauterbach support.

Comment: I guess, you have connected the MicroTrace to the 20-pin connector labeled with `Cortex debug + ETM` of your MCB1700 board, because with the other to debug connectors (labeled with "JTAG" and "Cortex debug"), tracing will not work.

Comment: Hi Mr. Holger, thank you very much for your explanation. Sorry that i am lack of knowledge for this topics. I would like to ask if i am able to trace using the given demo script , is that mean my Lauterbach MicroTrace MIPI20T connector able to access the physical trace pins? For the mentioned setting up of pin multiplexer , the command is Data.Set and the address of the Trace pin of the board which is pin 67 to pin 73?